# Backbone.localStorage An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I'm using Backbone.localStorage found at this site [jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage). I have had great success with this plugin and like what it has to offer me for local storage with some of my Backbone Collections.

With a recent deployment though nothing is getting saved in local storage in IE11 and when trying to debug I see the following error in IE11 developer tools debug console.

**An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions. File: backbone.localStorage.js, Line: 107, Column: 5.** If I look in my copy of the Backbone.localStorage.js file this is what is at line 107.

```js
  localStorage: function() {
    return localStorage;
  },
```

Did some searching online and haven't found a solution to this one yet. Has anyone else run into this problem and know how to fix? The strange part of this is that it did work before and it works in DEV environment but now is an issue on user machine. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Is the browser in compatibility mode?